# Jumping player in XNA using touchpad

Tags: c#, xna

In below code I am using two textures for player. is its normal animation and another for its jumping animation. While running with following code  at the time jumping only few of frames are running not all.

```cs
public void draw(Object sender,GameTimerEventArgs e) 
{
        jumpframe++;

        if (jumpframe > 32)
        {
            jumpframe = 0;
        }

        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.Tap;
        TouchCollection touches = TouchPanel.GetState();
        if ( touches.Count >0)
        {
            touch = true;
            jump();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("touch");
        }
        else if (touches.Count == 0)
        {
            playerr();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(currentframe);
            touch = false;
        }
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.player[currentframe], Texture.position, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.jumpplayer[jumpframe], Texture.jumpposition, Color.White);

        currentframe++;
        if (currentframe > 24)
        {
            currentframe = 0;
        }

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jumpframe);
        spriteBatch.End();
        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
    }

    public void jump()
    {
            Texture.jumpposition.X = 10;
            Texture.jumpposition.Y = 243;
            Texture.position.X = -200;
            Texture.position.Y = 243;
    }

    public void playerr()
    {
        Texture.position.X = 10;
        Texture.position.Y = 243;
        Texture.jumpposition.X = -400;
        Texture.jumpposition.Y = 243;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `jumpframe` is incremented and `Texture.jumpplayer[jumpframe]` is scanned correctly I think your problem is in `Texture.jumpposition` definition.

Just a suggestion: detect touches in your `Update` method, not in the `Draw`, that method should only be used for drawing instructions.